# How can I make a function only possible to be called by certain subclasses in c++?

Tags: c++

I have a class `base` with a private array (I cannot make it protected).
I have getters and setters set for objects in the array.
`base` has a subclass `sub1` and `sub1` has a subclass `sub2`.

Is there a way to make `sub1` only able to access some of `base`'s getter's and setter's and make `sub2` able to access other getters and setters?

Something with virtual methods perhaps?

Comment: `...sub1 only able to access some of "sub"'s getter's and setter's...`. What is `sub` now (did you mean `base`) ? Why only **some** of the getter and setter ?

Comment: Your architecture looks weird. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Maybe what you really want is class composition instead of inheritance.  Make your base class a member instead of a parent and play with that a bit.

Comment: A pure virtual method would have to be implemented in both sub1 and sub2.  You could provide a default implementation in `base` that returns null (or something like that), but this I believe is commonly referred to as "interface bloat".  I would look at having `sub1` and `sub2` contain rather than inherit from `base`.

Comment: Let's say `base` has `getFirst()` and `getAt()`, and they're both `public`; `sub1` has only `getAt()`; and `sub2()` only has `getFirst()`.  Both `sub1` and `sub2` violate the interface or "contract" of their parent(s) because one or more methods on the parent interface are missing from the child.  I would agree with @EtiennedeMartel that this looks odd; either try composition as suggested by @mydogisbox or make your interfaces more granular as suggested by @San Jacinto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Not in any good fashion

If you want this, you should break your base class into better granularity by creating several polymorphic interfaces and instead pass those interfaces around via pointer or reference so that each class only sees the functions it needs to see.

Comment: I think what you really mean is abstract base classes (this is C++ not Java or C#).

Comment: No. I mean "interfaces." Interfaces exist no matter what language you are using. You don't need the keyword "Interface" to create one; it's the concept that matters. It doesn't have to be a completely abstract class, though that may be most appropriate in any given circumstance.

Comment: @SanJacinto: I suppose you could get technical and say that an "interface" is a class from which you can inherit multiply and virtually at no extra cost compared to single inheritance  (e.g. a class with only pure-virtual functions and no members).

Comment: @Kerrek interfaces are a language feature in Java or C#, and a convention in C++.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel: I know - that's why I suggested that definition. It's not a necessary concept in C++, but that's the reason those other languages require it.